# Tossing two dice with sum equal to 4?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

**Exercise:**

> Throw two dice. Suppose that eye sum are 4.
>   Calculate the resulting conditional probability that
>
> a) the first dice gave a 3 . b ) the second dice gave two or fewer
>   eyes. c ) both dice showed an odd number of eyes.

I have no idea about how to "tackle" this task. Do you have any hints? I know that the total possible outcomes of these two dices are 36 and that the conditional probability is
$$P(B|A)=P( joint.of.events.A.and.B)/P(A)$$
but I do not know how to use this.

Comment: Just tabulate the possible outcomes, given that the sum is 4, and then look at the number of outcomes with those conditions.  No formulas for conditional probability needed.

Comment: ok thanks. I will try to solve it with your hint :) @Paul

Comment: We have the laplacian case here.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange!

Comment: Eye sum????????

Comment: the dots on the dices :) @barakmanos

Comment: The possible outcomes are 3, which gives the probability 3/36. The outcomes wich fulfills the condition in subtask a) is only one outcome (the outcome (3,1)). Therefore the probability is $(1/36)/(3/36)=1/3$ which is right answer. But have I done right? @Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Let $X$ denote the sum of eyes by throwing two dice and let $E$
be some event. Then

(*) $P\left(E\text{ and } X=4\right)=P\left(E\mid X=4\right)P\left(X=4\right)$

So finding $P\left(E\text{ and }X=4 \right)$ and $P\left(X=4\right)$ leads to finding
$P\left(E\mid X=4\right)$.

Apply this on the events mentioned in a), b) and c).

---

Let $D_{1}$
be the score of the first die and let $D_{2}$ be the score of the
second die.

If $i,j\in\left\{ 1,\dots,6\right\} $ then $P\left(D_{1}=i\text{ and }D_{2}=j\right)=P\left(D_{1}=i\right)P\left(D_{2}=j\right)=\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{36}$

Now let $E$ be the event that the first die gives a $3$ (as described as case a)).

Then $P\left(E\text{ and }X=4\right)=P\left(D_{1}=3\text{ and }D_{2}=1\right)=\frac{1}{36}$

Also $$P\left(X=4\right)=P\left(D_{1}=3\text{ and }D_{2}=1\right)+P\left(D_{1}=2\text{ and }D_{2}=2\right)+P\left(D_{1}=1\text{ and }D_{2}=3\right)=\frac{3}{36}$$

Substitution of this in (*) allows you to find $P\left(E\mid X=4\right)=\frac13$

Comment: with this i will use that the events E and X are independent, right? Then i will get $P(E)/P(X)$. But how shall i do if i want to use tree diagram, sum- and productrule? @drhab

Comment: should I on level 1 use event X and in level 2 use the events mentioned in the subtasks?

Comment: $X$ is not an event but a random variable. Then $X=4$ is an event. The events $E$ and $X=4$ are *not* independent here. I solved case a) to give you an example.

Comment: thanks alot! really good explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You have $3$ possible events in your probability-space:

```
 First Die | Second Die
-----------|------------
     1     |      3
-----------|------------
     2     |      2
-----------|------------
     3     |      1
```

---

Out of these $3$ events:

- There is $1$ event in which the first die gave 3, hence the probability is $\frac13$
- There are $2$ events in which the second die gave 2 or less, hence the probability is $\frac23$
- There are $2$ events in which both dice showed an odd number, hence the probability is $\frac23$

Comment: Thanks. But is my thinking in the comment above right?

Comment: @Ann: You're welcome. Yes, it is correct, but a bit of an overkill for the specific question at hand. For more complex questions, however, it might indeed be the correct approach.

Comment: Ok great! I try to answer the question detailed as possible to lern better and to let the classmates/teacher tell me if I think right or wrong. Thanks again :) @barakmanos

Comment: @Ann: You're welcome :)

Comment: sorry. i thought that i could accept two answers. my first time posting here in math stack

Comment: @Ann: No problem. You can only accept one, so you should accept the most appropriate one (if such one exists), and in this case - **even** if it's not mine :) ... You can up-vote or down-vote how many answers you'd like, but I think you need a minimum reputation in order to be able to do that.